# When did Henri Bertini publish his Etudes, Op. 32?

Tags: history

Can anyone say about when Henri Bertini published his Op. 32 of Etudes? IMSLP doesn't turn anything up.

Comment: This is maybe a better question for: https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/ than here...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is best fit for Music Fans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking in the [Bibliothèque nationale de France catalogue](https://catalogue.bnf.fr/) the earliest dated copy I can see is [1834](https://catalogue.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/cb42850698c), but that's a "nouvelle edition" of Op. 29 & Op. 32 together so the first publication would probably be earlier.

Op. 29 and Op. 32 are often published together and are kind of halves of a single work, so it would seem reasonable to guess they were composed about the same time. The earliest dated copy of Op. 29 the BNF have is [circa 1825](https://catalogue.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/cb42850701f), by which time it was already in the 4th edition. They have undated copies of both which look like they could be earlier, but unfortunately sheet music (and books) of that era didn't always have the date printed on it.

It looks like there was a [biography of Bertini](http://pascal.beyls.pagesperso-orange.fr/bertini/bertini.html) published in 1999 by Pascal Beyls (in French, ISBN 2-9513494-1-6) that includes a catalogue of works. It's not available on amazon.fr, but you could try contacting the author.

Answer (score 1):

I took a quick look for this and, to my surprise, I have not been able to find out the publication dates of most of his works.  Even good old Groves Dictionary did not help.

This site
[https://www.abebooks.com/servlet/BookDetailsPL?bi=21699222909&searchurl=tn%3Dhenri%2Bbertini%26sortby%3D17%26n%3D100121503&cm_sp=snippet-*-srp1-*-image12](https://www.abebooks.com/servlet/BookDetailsPL?bi=21699222909&searchurl=tn%3Dhenri%2Bbertini%26sortby%3D17%26n%3D100121503&cm_sp=snippet-_-srp1-_-image12)

is offering a third edition of Op32 for sale (at the time of writing anyway) and they have dated it as around 1840. So the first edition must have been a few years before that I guess. Not sure if that gets you any closer to your answer but its the best I can find.

Answer (score 1):

[IMSLP](https://imslp.org/wiki/24_Etudes%2C_Op.29_(Bertini%2C_Henri)) has this remark for op. 29/32:

> Probably first published rather earlier (than 1834 Simrock edition), if only since Bertini was already up to Op.66 (+) by the late 1820s already.

I conclude from this, that the first edition has still to be discovered.